# mongodb database with scala play 2.0 tutorial

Tags: scala, mongodb, playframework

Is there a tutorial how I can use mongodb database with scala play 2.0?

On the official website (playframework.org) there seems to be only the SQL example.

Answer (score 10):

Here's the official plugin for salat

https://github.com/leon/play-salat

Give me a shout if you can't get it working.

Comment: I am pretty new to programming with Scala + Play and was hoping to get some tutorials or any CRUD app using your plugin.
Google search didn't help :(

Answer (score 6):

Have you checked out this project:

https://github.com/vznet/play-mongo-jackson-mapper

Answer (score 2):

I spent some time on integration of the MongoDb support in the todo application (using salat extension) from the official Play Framework site.

https://github.com/Mironor/Play-2.0-Scala-MongoDb-Salat-exemple

Hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the ReactiveMongo plugin:

https://github.com/ReactiveMongo/Play-ReactiveMongo

It is for the 2.3 version of Play Framework and provides good instructions on how to add support for mongoDB data to your Play installation along with controller samples.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I have been working on this for sometime. Check my blog. You might find it useful. Let me know if you find any problem/mistake.

https://howtoscala.wordpress.com/2017/04/20/playing-with-mongodb-reactive-mongo/