# mongodb database with Java play 2.0

Tags: java, mongodb, playframework, playframework-2.0

Is there a tutorial how I can use mongodb database with Java play 2.0?

On the official website (playframework.org) there seems to be only the NoSql example.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

check this demo on github. https://github.com/czihong/playMongoDemo

I use morphia to connect play 2.o and mongodb.

Answer (score 2):

Check [mongodb database with scala play 2.0 tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9885257/mongodb-database-with-scala-play-2-0-tutorial) and [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/K7IrXyXvL8w/discussion). Unfortunately, there is no official tutorial at the moment.

Comment: Thanks for your information. This information is used to only scala project. But My Project is Java project. So i need mongo db connection Model.

Comment: check the second link I've given, it's about MongoDB wrapper for Play!2.0 - http://vznet.github.com/mongo-jackson-mapper/

Answer (score 0):

check this demo on github https://github.com/leodagdag/play2-morphia-plugin. This is not an official tutorial.this is a leodagdag.play2morphia.Model.