# Play Framework for Java 2.1 and MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb, playframework, playframework-2.1, mongodb-java

I'm about to build a project in Play Framework for Java 2.1 and I would like to use MongoDB to store data. I've installed both Play 2.1 and MongoDB 2.4.4.

Is it possible to build a Play! project with only the MongoDB Java Driver? I've actually tried to download the `mongo-java-driver.jar` which I placed in a `lib`/ folder in the `root` of my play project [according to this documentation](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/SBTDependencies). Then I've created a model in which I've added the code below but I can't get it to work. Do you know any tutorials or what am I doing wrong? I get compilation errors like `unreported exception java.net.UnknownHostException; must be caught or declared to be thrown`

```
import com.mongodb.MongoException;
import com.mongodb.WriteConcern;
import com.mongodb.DB;
import com.mongodb.DBCollection;
import com.mongodb.BasicDBObject;
import com.mongodb.DBObject;
import com.mongodb.DBCursor;
import com.mongodb.ServerAddress;

MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient();
```

Comment: You may find the solution to this question of use: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10022719/681807

Answer (score 2):

If you take a look at the [documentation](http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.10.1/com/mongodb/MongoClient.html), `MongoClient()` constructor may throw an `UnknownHostException`, which is a checked exception. You may either `catch` this exception in your code or add `throws UnknownHostException` declaration to your method.

Also read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/index.html) for exceptions in Java and [this](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=129) for checked vs. unchecked exceptions.